# Get fill on draw complex polygons on Google Maps Android API V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I draw a complex polygon that is not clockwise order in points without loosing color fill?

Comment: Please share the code that you've tried so far

Comment: Sure, i will edit my answer, here is the feature request I've seen:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/257

Answer (score 2):

Looks like still a missing feature :/